# При нажатии на кнопку появляется текстовое поле input для формы с помощью чистого JS. Как это реализовать правильно без JQuery?

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на кнопку появляется текстовое поле input для формы с помощью чистого JS. Как это реализовать правильно без JQuery?(изначальное задание: написать редактор форм)
Дайте подсказку, плиз, ребята)))хотя б пример с 1 инпутом и тегом <а>, покажите мне как надо, остальное самостоятельно осилю.
Заранее благодарю - Чтоб сила пребывала с вами, джедаи)
вот код

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="active">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="jsAddBtn">Добавить новое поле</a>
     <a href="javascript:;" class="jsEditBtn">Поле редактирования</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    <ul class="wrapper">
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="jstekst">Текст</a></li><br>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="jspunkt">Параграф</a></li><br>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="jschak">Чекбокс</a></li><br>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="jsrat">Множественный выбор</a></li><br>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="jssel">Выпадающий список</a></li><br>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="jsdt">Дата</a></li><br>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="jsnbr">Число</a></li><br> 
      </ul>

<form>
<input type="text" value="" name="one">
<input type="date" value="value" name="two">
<input type="checkbox" value="value" name="three">
<input type="radio" value="value">
<input type="number" value="value">
<textarea></textarea>
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого?

```js
function makeField() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="makeField()">Make a field</button>
```

Comment: ой, да, почти)))пасибушки за подсказку)))

Answer (score 0):

```
var handler_func = function ()
{
    var e = document.createElement('input');
    e.type='text';
    e.name = 'Enter your fav day';
    e.id = 'day';
    this.parentNode.appendChild(e);
    return false;
}
```